# How to Jest / Enzyme test a react-router-dom withRouter() wrapped component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component in React that gets exported with a `withRouter()` HOF wrapper. How can I test this component?

Enzyme error:

```
Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Palette) /> outside a <Router>
```

How I am exporting the component:

```
export default withRouter(Palette);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to export two variants of your component: one for the normal developing environment, the other for your testing environment.

Testing

```
// named export for the testing version
// src/components/Palette/Palette.js
export const Palette = props => { ... }

// import this version into the test and continue as usual...
// src/components/Palette/Palette.test.js
import React from "react";
import { Palette } from "./Palette";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { shallowToJson } from "enzyme-to-json";

describe("Palette", () => {
  it("should match the snapshot", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Palette />);
    expect(shallowToJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Regular

```
// default export for the normal version
// src/components/Palette.js
export default withRouter(Palette);
```

Essentially, export two versions with different intended purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping withRouter on arrow function while declaring the component, example

```
const Palette = withRouter(({ //propsHere }) => {

   //component content here

 }); 

export default Palette;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to doubled `export` is using `<MemoryRouter>` or [`<StaticRouter>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/StaticRouter.md) in tests like

```
 const wrapper = shallow(<StaticRouter location={someUrl}><Palette /></StaticRouter>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
let wrapper = shallow(<componentName.WrappedComponent/>);
```